# List all files containing a specific string

Tags: bash

I need to recursively look for all files containing a specific string so that I can copy a new file over the old one.  E.g.:

If a file has the string "replace me":

1. find the full path of the files:

   ```
   /dir/of/file/filename.php
   /dir/of/different/file/filename.php
   ```
2. replace the file with my new `filename.php` file.

It sounds simple, but I have wasted several hours on it getting nowhere.

Comment: Here is an example http://wilddiary.com/find-files-containing-my-text/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find some/dir \
    -exec grep -q "replace me" {} \; \
    -exec cp some/new/filename.php {} \;
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use this.  how do I test this output before i run cp?

Comment: Put an `echo` before the `cp`.

Comment: @ScottElkin: `find` can look like black magic, but basically it's just a series of sequential tests or actions that only get run if previous ones return true. You could change the second `-exec` up to it's closing `\;` statement to be simply `-print` to show what was matched by the previous statements. You could also add an "echo" before the cp to print out a preview of the commands that would be run.

Comment: this works!  I am having the same problem as I said below, where it is finding files I don't want.  can I filter the results down to certain php files and ignore the rest?

Comment: You can add as many predicates as you like. The `find(1)` man page details them all.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, but I don't understand what a predicate is.  I am a VERY green w/ linux.

Comment: I think I worked it out like "find some/dir -name thumb.php \", right?

Comment: Correct. `-name` is the predicate that uses a glob to match the filename of the item being looked at.

Comment: how would you check multiple names?  can you use -name twice?  it seems to hang when I try.

Comment: I just wrote a script with multiple find's - it works, but just wanted to know a better way, since I am learning so much from you guys.

Comment: You can use multiple `-name` predicates using an OR clause like this: `find /path \( -name firstname -or -name secondname -or -name thirdname \) ...`.

Answer (score 5):

[Ignacio's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19056/list-all-paths-and-filenames-matching-search/19057#19057) with `find` is probably the best way. Here it is with all the details from comments incorporated. I am specifically only searching for files (not directories) then grouping three statements together in a group with or statements to match any of the names:

```
find /dir/ \
    -type f \
    \( -name timthumb.php -or -name thumb.php -or -name rt-timthumb.php \) \
    -exec grep -q "timthumb" {} \; \
    -exec cp filename.php {} \;
```

However you could also do the finding with just shell glob patterns as well, something like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in /dir/**{timthumb,thumb,rt-timthumb}.php; do
    grep -q 'timthumb' "$file" && cp filename.php "$file"
done
```

You could also use the grep to do the recursive search instead of globbing. This would be useful if you had a lot of files:

```
grep -l -R -Z 'timthumb' /dir/**thumb.php | while read -d $'\0' file; do
    cp filename.php "$file"
done
```

In all cases replace "/dir/" with the base path you want to operate on and "filename.php" with the source file you are going to overwrite with. Quote as necessary. Note that in the last example I used a shortcut to match all files whos names match "*thumb.php". You could do this in the other examples too. In the case of find, you could drop the whole set of OR statements in parens and just use `-name '*thumb.php'`. All of the above examples will only operate on filesthat match those name patterns AND contain the string 'timthumb'.

Comment: the first one didn't work.  "/dir/**/*.php" is not a directory error.

Comment: the second one, when i echo "$file", does not just spit out a path, but a huge list of occurances where it found the string.  It is finding non php pages, and find many pages 10+ times since the string occurs multiple times in a page

Comment: @ScottElkin: Sorry about that. The first one probably chocked because you don't actually have subdirectories and that was ONLY matching subdirectiries. I edited it to match in the current folder or subdirectories. For the second one you need to use the `-l` option to grep to output just the file name match. Sorry I missed that typing it up.

Comment: wow, caleb, that is great.  now it is giving me all the file paths (like I asked), but it is finding other files I wasn't expecting - files that i don't want to overwrite with filename.php.  Is there a way to find only files that are named filename.php?

Comment: to make sure I don't waste your time - I want to replace all timthumb.php files, along with thumb.php (if 'timthumb' is found within) and rt-timthumb.php.  All the rest of the files it finds like log files, function files, I want to ignore.

Comment: You can use the shell glob pattern matching to only return matches for those file names. I'll edit my answer to match that scenario. You should have been much more specific in your original question :)

Comment: @ScottElkin: Your question still isn't quite clear. Are you trying to match the file names OR files that contain that string or BOTH? My answer is written up for those being a boolean AND condition. All files have to match both the name and have that string inside before they are operated on. If you meant something else you need to re-write your question to clarify.